How to fix ImportError: dlopen(): symbol not found in flat namespace '_mysql_affected_rows' on Mac M1
I am having an issue with running a script within a python virtual environment.
I have installed MySQL, MySQL client, Django, and everything using Homebrew since I am on a Mac M1 (Apple M1 Pro running Sonoma 14.4).  When I double-check this using pip install, I always get a requirement satisfied message.  Also, I have no issues starting up a database within MySQL and accessing this database.
I have seen some information that this is a version error, but uninstalling and re-installing MySQL with arch arm64 brew install mysql provides the same errors as above.  I have also seen some information saying to install just the specific library that is missing, but I am not sure which one that is in this case.
This is the complete error I am getting:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/giuseppespartico/Desktop/jrc-folder/biomonenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/Users/giuseppespartico/Desktop/jrc-folder/biomonenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/giuseppespartico/Desktop/jrc-folder/biomonenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-312-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_mysql_affected_rows'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/giuseppespartico/Desktop/jrc-folder/kcb-ds/./manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/giuseppespartico/Desktop/jrc-folder/kcb-ds/./manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/giuseppespartico/Desktop/jrc-folder/biomonenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/giuseppespartico/Desktop/jrc-folder/biomonenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/giuseppespartico/Desktop/jrc-folder/biomonenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/giuseppespartico/Desktop/jrc-folder/biomonenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/giuseppespartico/Desktop/jrc-folder/biomonenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/giuseppespartico/Desktop/jrc-folder/biomonenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/giuseppespartico/Desktop/jrc-folder/biomonenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 57, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/giuseppespartico/Desktop/jrc-folder/biomonenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 143, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/giuseppespartico/Desktop/jrc-folder/biomonenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 371, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/giuseppespartico/Desktop/jrc-folder/biomonenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 243, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/giuseppespartico/Desktop/jrc-folder/biomonenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/giuseppespartico/Desktop/jrc-folder/biomonenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/giuseppespartico/Desktop/jrc-folder/biomonenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 193, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/giuseppespartico/Desktop/jrc-folder/biomonenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/giuseppespartico/Desktop/jrc-folder/biomonenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?


Does anyone know how to fix this?

Did you use pip to install MySQL as well to address the “Did you install mysql client?” error message you identified?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49893339/475228

There is a second more involved answer on macOS calling for specific mysql_conf changes.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51600428/475228

